# How to assign memory to a var in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, memory, assign

I'm making an app with Flutter that will, eventually, have to deal with rather large dictionaries (~5500 entries). The data for the dictionary is generated dynamically (basically a function that hashes the entries of another dictionaries into a single byte).

I will end up with a hashing dict that has a key of exactly 10 bytes and a value of exactly a single byte:

```
{"ABCDEFGHIJ": 0, "KLMNOPQRST": 1, ... }
```

I believe Dart is a dynamically typed language so in debugging mode I tried to look up how an existing dict was created. Visual studio has a functionality called "Run and debug" for this. Under there is a tab called "Variables". However, it only shows that the dict was declared as a map. So I tried experimenting myself. I have declared the map globally as follows:

```
var hashes = Map<String, Uint8>;
```

There are still a few problems with this method. Upon declaring the variable, I don't know yet how big it is going to be. Also, I don't know how to set a fixed string length up front.

Say that I have 10 values to hash at a given point. I want to dynamically assign the space for 10 `<String, Uint8>` entries at ONCE and then assign each key/value pair.

Is this doable? And if so, how?

Comment: Maybe a database would make more sense when handling so many entries? Also, if it is a good `Map` implementation it would grow by itself when adding new entries.

Comment: Wouldn't you trust the authors of `LinkedHashMap` to have done a good job allocating enough hash table space and expand it as needed? Maybe you are optimizing prematurely...

Comment: There is no direct way to do this in Dart.  Dart memory is garbage-collected, and thus all memory is expected to be managed for you.  If you really wanted, you could create your own `Map` implementation that is backed by a `Uint8List`.  However, it would be a lot of work, and `Uint8List` is not growable.  You also perhaps could use `dart:ffi`.  Realistically, 5500 entries is not very many, and I'd just use a normal `Map<String, int>` unless profiling indicates that there actually is a performance or space problem.

Comment: A database would indeed make more sense. In a later stage this will probably the way to go. For now I'm going to stick with another method. I'll create the hashes on a server and send them over to the client. Thanks for all your suggestions :)